# .NET HttpClient.sendAsync is slow

Tags: c#, .net, performance, service, dotnet-httpclient

I have performance problem calling a REST API Service. I have a complex system, the client call to the server, the server call to the service. Everything is working, but the request time between server and service is too big, but only the request(1-1.5 sec), the response is fast. I have generated class to calling the service.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag",
    "13.0.5.0 (NJsonSchema v10.0.22.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0))")]
public partial class GeocodingClient 
{
    private string _baseUrl = "";
    private System.Net.Http.HttpClient _httpClient;
    private System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings> _settings;

    public GeocodingClient(string baseUrl, System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        BaseUrl = baseUrl; 
        _httpClient = httpClient; 
        _settings = new System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings>(() => 
        {
            var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
            UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(settings);
            return settings;
        });
    }

    public string BaseUrl 
    {
        get { return _baseUrl; }
        set { _baseUrl = value; }
    }

    //...
```

I measured the time between the communication. And the `var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);` method is slow. Every other is working fast.
I see the logs in the service, and it is log when the call is arriving. And the arriving time is slow. I tried call the service with Postman, and it is worked fine and fast.

```
/// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
/// <returns>Success</returns>
/// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenAreaResponse> GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenAreaAsync(GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenAreaRequest body, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/TechnicalObjectQuery/GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenArea");

    var client_ = _httpClient;
    try
    {
        using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            var content_ = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, _settings.Value));
            content_.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
            request_.Content = content_;
            request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("POST");
            request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

            PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
            var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
            request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);

            var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                        headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                }

                ProcessResponse(client_, response_);

                var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                if (status_ == "200") 
                {
                    var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenAreaResponse>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return objectResponse_.Object;
                }
                else
                if (status_ != "200" && status_ != "204")
                {
                    var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                    throw new ApiException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + (int)response_.StatusCode + ").", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, null);
                }

                return default(GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenAreaResponse);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response_ != null)
                    response_.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

I have other service with similar construction, but for other thigs, and it is working fast.

Why is this problem? What can I do with this?

Comment: Which version of .NET? Are you calling this function using `await` or are you doing `.Wait` or `.Result`?

Comment: @Charlieface I am using .NET 6.0. Calling the function with await.

Comment: Appending an underscore `_` to all local variables makes your code much less readable IMHO. Have you seen this convention anywhere, or it's your personal style?

Comment: Also here in StackOverflow the appearance of the horizontal scrollbar impedes immensely the readability of code snippets. Would you like to break the long lines in the `GetCanalizationLocationsBetweenAreaAsync` method, by adding line-breaks, so that all the code is visible with just vertical scrolling?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the code was generated by NSwag.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Let's just say that NSwag's style in general leaves a lot to be desired. The huge amount of boiler-plate, and the lack of `using` blocks, are just a few other issues.